# PHPList not able to connect to smtp server

Tags: server, smtp, phpmailer, phplist

Please guys help me.

### This is my config:

```
$mail->SMTPAuth = true;
define('PHPMAILERHOST', 'tonyfintech.info'); 
$phpmailer_smtpuser = 'info@tonyfintech.info'; 
$phpmailer_smtppassword = 'azerty123';
$phpmailer_smtpport = '587'; 

$phpmailer_smtpsecure = 'tls';
$mail->SMTPOptions = array(
        'ssl' => array(
            'verify_peer' => false,
            'verify_peer_name' => false,
            'allow_self_signed' => false
        )
    );


define('TEST', 0);
define('PHPMAILER_SMTP_DEBUG', 1);
```

---

```
I still have this error:
2018-10-30 21:04:23 CLIENT -> SERVER: EHLO tonyfintech.info
2018-10-30 21:04:23 CLIENT -> SERVER: STARTTLS
SMTP Error: Could not connect to SMTP host.
2018-10-30 21:04:23 CLIENT -> SERVER: QUIT
```

---

This configuration works well in my other server but not this one.
By the way, When I send an email using PHPMailer "just for testing" , it works with no issue .
The issue come from PHPList

Answer (score 0):

The fact that it works on one server but not another suggests it's an environmental problem, not your code. The most likely explanation is that your server's CA certificate bundle is outdated, which is covered extensively on here and in [the PHPMailer troubleshooting guide](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/wiki/Troubleshooting).

You should not be disabling certificate verification, though at a guess I'd say that PHPList isn't using your PHPMailer instance, which is probably why it's failing, because the certificate verification disabling you've done only applies to PHPMailer, not PHPList.

Fix your certificates and it will work in both.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I resolved the issue by changing my php version From 5.6.x to 5.5.x

Comment: Eek. No. Don’t do that. You are “fixing” your problem by making your script vulnerable to man in the middle attacks. Like I said, fix your server, update your CA certs and your script will work.